# OctoberCMS - Report for my booking using a chart or scoreboard

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm quite new with octobercms so is there any documented or any guide in using scoreboard/chart in octobercms? I have to do a booking report using those two but for now I need some guide and help on how to start doing it. For example on how to put data of total booking as a line graph base on date/month or anything similar

Comment: checkout this tutorial https://tutorialmeta.com/october-cms/how-to-use-charts-in-octobercms may be it can be a help

Comment: you can add `data-chart-options='xaxis:{ show: false }, yaxis:{ show: false }'` to hide axis respectivly

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you have specific code examples, but yes, here are the docs on the scoreboard:

https://octobercms.com/docs/ui/scoreboard

Click on Show Source next to each example.